# How to suppress cronie logs under systemd?

Tags: systemd, cron, logs

I have a job scheduled in cron (cronie 1.5.1-r0). It fills my syslog (systemd 234) with

```
Nov 19 11:02:01 hometest CROND[1031]: (root) CMD (^I/usr/bin/some_script.py)
```

because I do this every minute. I need to temporarily get rid of these messages (the important things are rotated away and I don't have enough space), so I put this into `/etc/systemd/system/crond.service.d/silent_stdout.conf`:

```
[Service]
StandardError=null
StandardOutput=null
```

The configuration applies correctly, according to `systemctl cat crond.service`:

```
# /lib/systemd/system/crond.service
[Unit]
Description=Periodic Command Scheduler

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/crond
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/crond -n $CRONDARGS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# /etc/systemd/system/crond.service.d/silent_stdout.conf
[Service]
StandardError=null
StandardOutput=null
```

but the lines are still appearing, even after reboot. What am I missing?

Comment: check with `crontab -l` (as the user which run it)

Comment: @RomeoNinov what am I searching for? From the crontab point of view everything is OK, the script runs every minute. What I need is systemd to discard all crontab output.

Comment: Check your logger config and add remark to lines, related to cron. Do not forget to restart logger after that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suppress all the logs of cron you should edit `/etc/rsyslog.conf` (or whatever your logger is) and search for line:

```
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
```

(path may differ)
and comment it:

```
#cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
```

and then restart logger

Comment: I don't use any external logging tool. I only work with systemd journal.

Comment: @AdamTrhon, please check your daemons, I am 99.9% sure you will see `syslog`, `rsyslog` or something like. And this logger take care of writing those lines in log file. Logger - software which take care of write logs from different sources

Comment: my file is already commented like this and yet cron spams my journalctl -r

Comment: @Freedo, did you restart syslog daemon after you edit the config?

Comment: @RomeoNinov yes, it does't work